# Javassist capture local variable values for specific statements

Tags: java, instrumentation, javassist

I'm trying to capture the values of variables involved in a conditional expression of branch and loop statements eg:

```java
if (a + b < c - 5) { // here, capture value of a, b and c
    // if body
}

for (int i = 0; i / x < 4 ; i++){ // here, capture value of i and x on exit of loop
    // for body
}
```

Does Javassist provide ExpressionEditor for if, switch, for and while statements like it does for FieldAccess, MethodCall, Handler etc.?

Is there any other approach to this problem? (I'm interested in doing this at runtime)

Comment: Javassist does - other than suggested - allow you to iterate over all code instructions. From having worked with both Javassist and ASM I do however suggest you to look into ASM which is better suited for these forms of transformations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really think that this is possible, with Javassist you cannot go and visit this deep in the ByteCode.

Your needs are too fine grained and the library is not supporting it as you can see from [this](https://jboss-javassist.github.io/javassist/tutorial/tutorial2.html) document you can access to all the variables that are parameters of a method or return of a method but you cannot find anything about all the other variables.

If I may suggest something you should take a look at [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/). I am not an expert about it but, as I know and according to [this](http://asm.ow2.org/doc/tutorial.html) documentation should provide more insight view of the bytecode.